# Создать структуру с 3 полями(сообцы строки и матрица), функция выделения памяти под матрицу и функцию единичной матрицы

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, матрицы, структуры

**Задание звучит так: необходимо создать структуру с 3 полями(число строк, число столбцов и матрица). Далее необходимо создать функцию, которая будет выделать память под эту матрицу и функцию которая будет делать эту матрицу единичной. Далее надо ее распечатать. Вот что я сделал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так и что делать дальше.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrix {
    int row;
    int column;
    int *array;
};

struct matrix create(int n) {
   int* array = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
   struct matrix arr = {n, n, array};
   return arr;
}

int main() {

    struct matrix arr = create(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Матрица двумерная, так что две звёздочки должно быть `int **array`, вероятно, с отдельным выделением памяти под каждую строчку и под массив указателей на строки. И почему в create используется какое-то n, если нужны определенные число строк и столбцов?

Comment: @AlexF Если не затруднит, не могли бы Вы расписать как это должно выглядеть

Answer (score 0):

Начало верное. Скорее всего матрица должна была содержать не целые числа. Я бы переделал на тип чисел **double**.

```
struct matrix {
    int row;
    int column;
    double *array;
};

struct matrix create(int const n) {
   double * array = malloc((unsigned)n * (unsigned)n * sizeof(double));
   struct matrix arr = {n, n, array};
   return arr;
}
```

Далее удобнее написать функцию доступа к элементам по формуле

ширина_матрицы * номер_строки + номер_столбца

```
static  inline  double * matrix_elt  ( struct matrix * const mat ,
  int const r , int const c ) {
  return & ( mat -> array [ ( mat -> column ) * r + c ] ) ;
}
```

И потом уже ей пользоваться, создавая единичную матрицу и вывода на экран.

```
int main() {

  int const n = 3 ;
    struct matrix arr = create(n);
    
    for(int r=0;r<n;++r)
      for(int c=0;c<n;++c)
        * matrix_elt ( & arr , r , c ) = ( ( r == c ) ? 1 : 0 ) ;
      
  for(int r=0;r<n;++r){
      for(int c=0;c<n;++c)
        fprintf(stdout,"%6g",* matrix_elt ( & arr , r , c ));
      fputs("\n",stdout);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Matrix {
    int columns;
    int rows;
    int **containment;
};

// add space for matrix containment
void function_name_of_init_action(struct Matrix *matrix_pointer1) {
    matrix_pointer1->containment = (int **) malloc(matrix_pointer1->columns * sizeof(int *)); //add space for cols
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer1->columns; ++i) {
        matrix_pointer1->containment[i] = (int*) malloc(matrix_pointer1->rows * sizeof(int)); // add space for rows
    }
}

// make matrix with 1s on main diag
void fill_matrix(struct Matrix *matrix_pointer2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer2->columns; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix_pointer2->rows; ++j) {
            if (i == j) {     // main diag
                matrix_pointer2->containment[i][j] = 1;  // fill with const == 1
            }
        }
    }
}

// free space for matrix containment
void free_matrix(struct Matrix *matrix_pointer3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer3->columns; ++i) {
        free(matrix_pointer3->containment[i]);
    }
    free(matrix_pointer3->containment);
}

// print matrix
void print_matrix(struct Matrix *matrix_pointer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer->columns; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix_pointer->rows; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", matrix_pointer->containment[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    struct Matrix matrix_variable_name = {10, 10};   //init structure

    function_name_of_init_action(&matrix_variable_name);
    fill_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
    print_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
    free_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не инициализированы элементы за пределами главной диагонали. Поведение программы не определено.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).